# Counting instances of value in postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Bit of an SQL newbie question..

If I have a table along the lines of the following :

```
host    fault                                             fatal groupname
Host A  Data smells iffy                                  n     research
Host B  Flanklecrumpet needs a cuddle                     y     production
Host A  RAM loves EWE                                     n     research
Host Z  One of the crossbeams gone askew on the treadle   y     research
```

.. and I want to get some stats, I can..

`select count(distinct host) as hosts, count(host) as faults, group from tablename group by groupname`

.. which gives me the number of faults and affected hosts per groupname.

```
hosts    faults    groupname
2        3         research
1        1         production
```

Can I, in the same query, show the number of fatal entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use aggregation, but in Postgres would phrase this as:

```
select groupname, count(distinct host) as hosts,
       count(*) as num_faults,
       count(*) filter (where fatal = 'Y') as num_fatal
from t
group by groupname;
```

Answer (score 2):

use conditional aggregation

```
 select count(distinct host) as hosts,
 count(host) as faults,sum(case when fatal='y' then 1 else 0 end) as numberofenty,
 groupname from tablename group by groupname
```

Comment: I fear one of us has misunderstood but I'm not sure which one :)

I'd like the results to contain, per groupname, the number of rows where fatal == 'y'

Comment: Well, it did work but wasn't the solution I went for as the other one was, IMHO, cleaner.